# Ubuntu desktop not loading and only booting to command line

Tags: gnome

I have been trying to solve this problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 for the past two days.

I boot up my system, and it acts like the server edition of Ubuntu. It launches a full screen command line and that's it.

So far, I have tried reinstalling `gdm3` and `lightdm`. That did not work. I set my privileges on the `.Xauthority` file to my username, that did not work. I also reinstalled `gnome-panel` as some people said and that did  not work. Finally, I installed `lubuntu-desktop`, and set LXDM as my default desktop environment. It's still only loading the command line!

What else can I try?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that. I am currently running ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Try this `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` nad reboot

Comment: N0rbert, I have tried installing gnome panel and that did not work, still booted me to command line.

Comment: George Udosen, that is not working as well. But thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Found a half-solution, so i will answer my own question.

All I did was set default DM to LXDM, and surprisingly, that worked. So I guess I will just have to manage with this.